# Refactor C# Class with Generics from IUnityContainer to Ninject

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, ninject

I would like to move away from the Unity NuGet package for Dependency Injection and switch to Ninject since Unity is no longer being maintained. I was wondering if someone might be able to help me refactor the following Mediator class to use Ninject instead of IUnityContainer?

For example, should I be replacing the IUnityContainer with the Ninject StandardKernel?

Will I need to use the Ninject Bind method rather than the Unity Resolve method?

**Mediator.cs**

```
public sealed class Mediator : IMediator
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

    public Mediator(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public TResponse Request<TResponse>(IQuery<TResponse> query)
    {
        var handlerType = typeof(IQueryHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(query.GetType(), typeof(TResponse));
        dynamic handler = _container.Resolve(handlerType);

        return handler.Handle((dynamic)query);
    }

    public TResult Send<TResult>(ICommand<TResult> command)
    {
        var handlerType = typeof(ICommandHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(command.GetType(), typeof(TResult));
        dynamic handler = _container.Resolve(handlerType);

        return handler.Handle((dynamic)command);
    }
}
```

**IMediator.cs**

```
public interface IMediator
{
    TResponse Request<TResponse>(IQuery<TResponse> query);
    TResult Send<TResult>(ICommand<TResult> command);
}
```

**IQuery.cs**

```
public interface IQuery<out TResponse> { }
```

**IQueryHandler.cs**

```
public interface IQueryHandler<in TQuery, out TResponse> where TQuery : IQuery<TResponse>
{
    TResponse Handle(TQuery query);
}
```

**ICommand.cs**

```
public interface ICommand<out TResult> { }
public interface ICommand { }
```

**ICommandHandler**

```
public interface ICommandHandler<in TCommand, out TResult> where TCommand : ICommand<TResult>
{
    TResult Handle(TCommand command);
}

public interface ICommandHandler<in TCommand> where TCommand : ICommand
{
    void Handle(TCommand command);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Mediator.cs**

```
public sealed class Mediator : IMediator
{
    private readonly IKernel _container;

    public Mediator(IKernel container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public TResponse Request<TResponse>(IQuery<TResponse> query)
    {
        var handlerType = typeof(IQueryHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(query.GetType(), typeof(TResponse));

        var request = _container.CreateRequest(handlerType, null, new Parameter[0], true, true);
        var handlerList = _container.Resolve(request);
        dynamic handler = handlerList.SingleOrDefault();

        return handler.Handle((dynamic)query);
    }

    public TResult Send<TResult>(ICommand<TResult> command)
    {
        var handlerType = typeof(ICommandHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(command.GetType(), typeof(TResult));

        var request = _container.CreateRequest(handlerType, null, new Parameter[0], true, true);
        var handlerList = _container.Resolve(request);
        dynamic handler = handlerList.SingleOrDefault();

        return handler.Handle((dynamic)command);
    }
}
```